# Finding the minimum of 3 variables using an if statement

Tags: java, bluej

I'm learning how to use BlueJ and I am struggling in writing the code for it to output the minimum number that the user has inputted. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FindMin
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("Program to compare three numbers");
        System.out.println("and output minimum value entered");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter 1st number: ");
        int number1;
        number1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter 2nd number: ");
        int number2;
        number2 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter 3rd number: ");
        int number3;
        number3 = input.nextInt();

        int minimum;
        if (number2 > number1 | number3 > number1){
            minimum = number1;
        }
        else if (number1 > number2 | number3 > number2){
            minimum = number2;
        }
        else if (number1 > number3 | number2 > number3){
            minimum = number3;
        }

        System.out.print("The minimum of the numbers entered is ");
        System.out.println(minimum); 
        System.out.println(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Java !== JavaScript. please use the relevant tags only

Answer (score 2):

`|` is the bitwise OR operator. You want `&&`, the logical AND operator. "If `number2` is greater than `number1` **and** `number3` is greater than `number1`." Also, you don't want any `if` on the last `else`, since by then you've ruled out two of the three possibilities and there's only one possibility left.

Separately, we'll want to handle the case where `number1` and `number2` are the same, and they're both lower than `number3`. That can be done by using `>=` instead of `>` in the first `if`.

So:

```
if (number2 >= number1 && number3 > number1) {
    // −−−−−^−−−−−−−−−−^^
    minimum = number1;
} else if (number1 > number2 && number3 > number2) {
    // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^
    minimum = number2;
} else /* No `if` here */ {
    minimum = number3;
}
```

JavaScript example (since the logic and syntax of the above is common to both Java and JavaScript):

```js
function test(number1, number2, number3) {
    let minimum;
    if (number2 >= number1 && number3 > number1) {
        // −−−−−−^−−−−−−−−−^^
        minimum = number1;
    } else if (number1 > number2 && number3 > number2) {
        // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^
        minimum = number2;
    } else /* No `if` here */ {
        minimum = number3;
    }
    console.log(minimum);
}

test(1, 2, 3); // Should be 1
test(3, 2, 1); // Should be 1
test(2, 2, 1); // Should be 1
test(2, 2, 4); // Should be 2
```

Comment: This would fail if number1 and number2 are different value, it will pick number3. It should have been with lesst han or equal operation

Comment: @Nap - LOL, fair point. I just looked at the operators and didn't audit the operations. I've fixed it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also `import java.util.*` witch comes with `java.lang.Math`. This allows you to use methods that come from `Math`, such as `Math.min`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FindMin
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("Program to compare three numbers");
        System.out.println("and output minimum value entered");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter 1st number: ");
        int number1;
        number1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter 2nd number: ");
        int number2;
        number2 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter 3rd number: ");
        int number3;
        number3 = input.nextInt();

         int minimum = Math.min(Math.min(number1, number2), number3);

        System.out.print("The minimum of the numbers entered is ");
        System.out.println(minimum); 
        System.out.println(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this

```
int minimum = 0;
    if(number1 < number2){
        minimum = number1;
    }else{
        minimum = number2;
    }
    if(number3<minimum){
        minimum = number3;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below method and pass your three numbers as parameters.

```java
    public static int getMinimumNumber(int no1, int no2, int no3) {
        return no1 < no2 ? (no1 < no3 ? no1 : (no2 < no3 ? no2 : no3)) : (no2 < no3 ? no2 : no3);
    }
```